# How to partition based on part of json field when using kafka-connect to ingest data to s3

Tags: json, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use the s3-sink kafka connector to store some json data into s3. My json format is as following:

```
{
   "server": someserver,
   "id": someid,
   "time": "2018-01-18T23:47:03.737487Z"
}
```

I want to partition my data based on what hour it lies in but ignore the minutes and seconds. eg. the above json will belong to 2018-01-18T23 directory. How should I set the field.partition in the properties file to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough way to achieve what you describe with [Confluent's S3 connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/index.html) is to:

- Define the property `timestamp.extractor` to be `RecordField`, to extract the timestamp from a field on your records.
- Set the property `timestamp.field` to the name of that record field (`time` in your example)
- Set `path.format` property. This will allow you to bucket your files up to hour, as you mention in your example, ignoring finer granularities (minutes, seconds, etc).
- Also set `partition.duration.ms` to a meaningful granularity for you. Important is that the default value of `-1` will not allow you to use time-based partitioning.
- Finally, set the properties `locale` and `timezone` too if you are using one of the predefined partitioners or a custom time-based partitioner that is relevant.

Note that there is a predefined time-based partitioner class shipped with the connector, which you might find useful for your use-case. You may use it by setting:

`partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner`

Comment: Thank you so much Konstantine. This is what I need.

Comment: I am getting this error - 'Value is not of Struct or Map type', when using above configuration. the topic contains json data. How to produce data in struct format?

Comment: @TimeTraveler did you find the solution? I am getting the same error

Comment: @rilut https://github.com/canelmas/kafka-connect-field-and-time-partitioner